Как увеличить лимит открытых файлов в Windows 10-11?
Мне для одной программы необходимо держать открытыми несколько тысяч файлов. Столкнулся с ограничениями OS. Вот пример:
a = []
for i in range(9000):
    print(i)
    a.append(open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8'))


Выдаёт ошибку:
8184
8185
8186
8187
8188
8189
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/тест лимита открытый файлов.py", line 4, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'test.txt'

Я нагуглил способы увеличения через редактирования реестра, прописывание различных команд и изменение переменных среды. Ни один из способов не помог. ChatGPT так же не дал рабочих вариантов. Можете подсказать как увеличить этот лимит? Нужно найти решения для Windows 10 и Windows 11.

Выглядит как проблема XY. Чего вы на самом деле пытаетесь добиться?

open() возвращает объект TextIOWrapper и количество таких объектов в системе ограничено, так что если вы не будете закрывать свои файлы то закономерно будете посла... получите исключение.

Это не проблема XY. Я работаю с большим количеством файлов на большом количестве дисков. Необходимо максимально быстро получать доступ к произвольным точкам в указанном файле и при таком подходе задержка на открытие файла слишком велика.

@Amgarak
Если не вдаваться в подробности, то функция получает имя файла и позицию в нём и возвращает последовательность байтов из этой позиции. 2000 файлов, общим размером 6 TB. Количество выполняемых запросов - 20 000 в секунду в среднем. В пиках в несколько раз больше. При этом на каждый файл нужно несколько переменных, так как иначе возникает гонка за ресурсы (многопоточная программа). Я хочу увеличить скорость выполнения запросов, добавив новые диски с дубликатами данных и распаралелив запросы, но возникает такая проблема с лимитами файлов.

Вы используете неправильный инструмент. Тут нужна база данных, а не 100500 файлов .

@Эникейщик Я как бы разрабатываю собственную базу данных, под специальный тип задач. В этом и весь смысл.

Насколько я знаю, Винда позволяет только 10 тысяч хэндлов на процесс. Так что нужно либо другой алгоритм применять, либо использовать несколько процессов (но межпроцессный обмен может убить производительность).

Вернее, так было когда-то давно. С тех пор, с переходом на 64 бита лимиты во много раз увеличились. Но точно сказать не могу. Да и в разных источниках хендлы указываются разные: файлы, графические объекты, мьютексы и пр. Но, думаю, в любом случае держать тысячи файлов открытыми одновременно - это тупиковый путь.

Обычно движки баз данных выделяют большое пространство на диске под свои нужды, разбивают его на страницы и держат всего одно соединение (один хендл), самостоятельно поддерживая таблицу ссылок на страницы. Копайте в сторону аналогичной реализации.

Вот разрабы SQLite хвастают: 35% Faster Than The Filesystem

@Alexander Petrov
В обычных базах данных важна и скорость чтения и скорость записи. Когда записывать данные не нужно, можно всё делать куда быстрее. По ссылке написано, что SQLite производила 100к чтений по 10кб за 1 секунду.
А вот мой код на питоне:
f = open(name_file,'rb')
f = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
l = len(f)
t = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
n = randint(0,l)
data = f[n:n+10000]
print(time.time()-t)
И он тоже выполняется примерно за секунду. Только читает не 100к записей, а 1 миллион. И файл у меня не 1 гигабайт, а 16.

Код поехал, но думаю всё понятно. Готовые СУБД слишком универсальны, что бы быть максимально эффективными в узких областях.

В интернетах пишут, что Windows Server в этом плане более гибкий, там это настраивается как-то. Ещё можно Linux попробовать. Зачем вам именно Win 10/11? Движки БД на потребительских ОС обычно не гоняют.

"Готовые СУБД слишком универсальны, что бы быть максимально эффективными в узких областях." - существуют более узкоспециализированные no-sql СУБД, возможно какой-то вариант вам бы подошел. Я бы начал с ресерча в этом направлении, а не пытался взять у ОС то чего она не может дать.

Если потом будете искать по этим данным, проще например elasticsearch взять, который конкретно под это и заточен.

По буквальной формулировке задачи - не пытаться все файлы открыть. Если есть какой-то заметный оверхэд на открытие/закрытие, то держите постоянно открытыми, например, 100 файлов. Если нужно записать что-то в еще не открытый файл - закрывать файл, к которому давно не было обращений, новый открывать.

"И он тоже выполняется примерно за секунду. Только..." - не имеет таких же гарантий надёжности, какие предоставляют нормальные СУБД
